# Will an illegal reflective access operation prevent a program from running?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am working on a project using java and flink to build a data stream of tweets. When I run the program I receive this error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment (file:/home/haydn/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-core/1.4.2/flink-core-1.4.2.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

The program seems to run afterwards though, so I'm just wondering if this error means anything will not be working as intended, or if everything will be fine.

I noticed other posts in which people gave suggestions on how to hide the message, which is why I assumed it wasn't critical.

Thanks :)

Comment: It is a warning and not an error, so it is not necessarily critical.

Answer (score 5):

> so I'm just wondering if this error means anything will not be working as intended, or if everything will be fine.

To check this you need to write tests for your application. Since this is only a warning it by itself should not break your application.

> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

This means that your application will work now but will stop working once you upgrade your JDK to a new release. Because of concept of modules introduced in Java 9 `public` access modifier doesn't have the same meaning as in prior Java versions. And that warning above means that code of one of Flink libraries tries to access property `java.nio.Buffer.address` which is not exported to that module.